# How many ways am I doing this c# concurrent task management incorrectly?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, task-parallel-library

I'm writing an application that crawls a website and does various tests on each page. I'd like the option to have the crawler run several concurrent crawls of the website at once. I have a semi-working...solution. This will crawl the website OK with 1 task, when I sent it to max concurrent tasks 2 it runs faster as expected. However when I set it to 3 or above it seems slower. I'm from a PHP background so I'm fairly sure I'm doing this in the worst possible way.

```
var DontLockGuiTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (tokenSource2.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Logger.AddToActivityLog("Tasks stopped by user");
            break;
        }

        if (URLsToCheck.Count == 0 && CurrentNumberOfScrapes == 0)
        {
            EndOfCheck = true;
            break;
        }

        lock ("CurrentNumberOfScrapes")
        {
            CurrentNumberOfScrapes++;
        }

        var ScrapeTask = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (EndOfCheck)
            {
                CurrentNumberOfScrapes--;
                return;
            }

            URLCheckResultObject CheckResultForURL;

            Checker Checker                 = new Checker();
            URLsToCheckObject URLToCheck    = new URLsToCheckObject();

            lock ("URLsToCheck")
            {
                if (URLsToCheck.Count == 0)
                {
                    lock ("CurrentNumberOfScrapes")
                    {
                        CurrentNumberOfScrapes--;
                        return;
                    }
                }

                URLToCheck = URLsToCheck.First();
                URLsToCheck.Remove(URLToCheck);
            }

            CheckResultForURL = Checker.PerformCheckOnURL(URLToCheck, this);

            PagesCrawledCounter++;
            ChecksPerformedCounter += CheckResultForURL.Checkcounter;

            CheckResultForURL.URLID = PagesCrawledCounter;

            Logger.AddToActivityLog("Checking " + URLToCheck.URLAddress + "....");

            if(CheckResultForURL.NewListOFURLSToCheck != null)
            {
                foreach (LinkObject NewURLToAdd in CheckResultForURL.NewListOFURLSToCheck)
                {
                    lock ("URLsToCheck")
                    {
                        string CleanURL = NewURLToAdd.destinationURL;

                        if (CleanURL.EndsWith("/"))
                        {
                            CleanURL = CleanURL.Substring(0, CleanURL.Length - 1);
                        }

                        if (URlsWeKnownAbout.Contains(CleanURL)) continue;

                        URlsWeKnownAbout.Add(CleanURL);
                        URLsToCheck.Add(new URLsToCheckObject { URLAddress = CleanURL, Host = host });
                    }
                }
            }

            CheckResultForURL.NewListOFURLSToCheck = null;

            if(CheckResultForURL.SocialCheckResult != null)
            {
                ProblemID++;
                CheckResultForURL.SocialCheckResult.URLID = ProblemID;
                InsertSQLProblemIntoDataGrid(CheckResultForURL.SocialCheckResult);
            }

            lock ("CurrentNumberOfScrapes")
            {
                CurrentNumberOfScrapes--;
            }
        });

        while (CurrentNumberOfScrapes >= CurrentNumberScrapesMax)
        {
            if (tokenSource2.IsCancellationRequested == true)
            {
                Logger.AddToActivityLog("Tasks stopped by user");
                break;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    EnableUsedGUIForRun();

}, tokenSource2.Token);
```

As you can see I have a couple of while loops that check to see how many current tasks are running and sleeps if no more are needed and starts new ones when old ones finish or the current amount of tasks is under the `CurrentNumberScrapesMax` level.

How should I approach this? I want to manage multiple concurrent tasks all accessing the same variables.

Comment: Approximately 7.

Comment: lock accepts an object (string is one too), and ensures that the reference for that object is "locked" for other threads. There will be the wait. Now You are locking the reference of the string, not the number itself. Use lock(<some new object which is not immutable>) instead.

Comment: Have you considered the parallel foreach option? aka Parallel.ForEach( values, new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = number}...)

Comment: Thanks I'll check out the Parallel.ForEach, looks promising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not add new tasks to `URLsToCheck`, then your code may be simplified to something like:

```
Parallel.ForEach(URLsToCheck,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Emvironment.ProcessorCount }, url => CrawlAcross(url));
```

But if you do get some more urls to crawl, then you need more complicated logic. You may give a try to [`TPL Dataflow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx) here, with pipeline like this:

```
Buffer with urls --> Crawl the url processor --> Result saving
```

where second part can post additional url back to buffer. So it can be like this:

```
var buffer = new BufferBlock<string>();
var processor = new TransformBlock<string, CrawlResult>(url => 
{
    var result = CrawlAcross(url);
    foreach (var additionalUrl in result.AdditionalUrlsToParse)
    {
        buffer.Post(additionalUrl);
    }
    return result;
});
var handler = new ActionBlock<CrawlResult>(r => HandleResult(r));

buffer.LinkTo(processor, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
processor.LinkTo(handler, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });

foreach (var url in URLsToCheck)
{
    buffer.Post(url);
}
```

Side notes about your code:

- `while` loops in tasks should be marked as `LongRunning`
- child tasks should be moved out
- `lock` statement should be done not on string constants, but on dedicated `static` objects for improved readability and predictive results
- `if (tokenSource2.IsCancellationRequested == true)` can be simplified to `if (tokenSource2.IsCancellationRequested)`
- if you got `tokenSource2.IsCancellationRequested` flag, you should call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`
- You should deal with token, not with tokenSource
- Maybe something else, it's hard to say